# Meaning of 유리아이

Tags: meaning

유리아이 is the Korean name of the song 'Lost in Love' by Taeyeon and Tiffany of Girls' Generation.

I know that *유리 琉璃* means *glass*, and I know that *아이* means *child*. However, when put together, *Glass Child* doesn't make much sense. Is it some kind of colloquialism or idiom in Korean? What does it actually mean?

Comment: I think it could be metaphorical portrayal of fragile mind of a said person.

Comment: @user300375 I think so, that's what I suspected, but I couldn't get confirmation (nor denial) from a native Korean so I asked. High-five for having the same idea xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that '유리' in the title means '유리 (流離)' as it is not a broadly used word.

Further research led me to the fact that Korean word '유리소년 (glass boy)' is quite popular among young Korean people which is a direct translation of a Japanese song '[硝子の少年](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%A1%9D%E5%AD%90%E3%81%AE%E5%B0%91%E5%B9%B4)' which is a debut single of [Kinki Kids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KinKi_Kids). According to the linked Wikipedia article:

> The duo made their debut in 1997 with a double release of a single
>   "Garasu no Shōnen" (硝子の少年?, "**Glass Boy**")

I believe '유리아이 (Glass Child)' and '유리소년 (Glass Boy)' have the same connotation in terms of interpreting what '유리' means.

'유리 (glass)' is transparent and easily broken (fragile). I think it metaphorically expresses the girl's mental status and sorrow after she broke up with her boyfriend.

'유리아이' could literally translates to '*glass child*'.